# Quick press doesn't change image in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an image that works like a button. When I click on this button, the image changes at the moment I press it, as if a Hover effect is created and when the user releases the button, the button returns to its normal form. But I ran into an error, if you quickly press and release the image does not have time to change. How can I fix this?

```
  bool isPressed = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTapCancel: () {
        setState(() {
          isPressed = false;
        });
      },
      onTapDown: (_) {
        setState(() {
          isPressed = true;
        });
      },
      onTapUp: (_) {
        setState(() {
          isPressed = false;
        });
        widget.onPressed(true);
      },
      child: Image.asset(
        isPressed
            ? constants.Assets.buttonPressed
            : constants.Assets.button,
        height: 56,
        width: 56,
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: add video or image

Comment: I've modified some parts & failed to reproduce the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not updating state while user tapping.

Try thid code

```
bool isPressed = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTapCancel: () {
        setState(() {
          isPressed = false;
        });
      },
      onTapDown: (_) {
        setState(() {
          isPressed = true;
        });
      },
      onTapUp: (_) {
        setState(() {
          isPressed = false;
        });
        widget.onPressed(true);
        setState(() {});  <------------------- add here setState.
      },
      child: Image.asset(
        isPressed
            ? constants.Assets.buttonPressed
            : constants.Assets.button,
        height: 56,
        width: 56,
      ),
    );
  }
```